# Compare two map keys in same index position

Tags: java, hashmap

Iam checking the memory address of file process are changed in second o/p

Here in second o/p, the address of file process 3rd /lib/libm-2.31.so is not changed. it is still same as that of first address b3ee7000-b3ee8000.

Similarly second  o/p, the address of file process ist  /lib/libm-2.31.so is not changed . it is still b3e74000-b3ec5000

How can i validate this using java Hashmap.
I did comparisons but not working

```
    String output1 = "b3e74000-b3ec5000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
            + "b3ec5000-b3ed4000 ---p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
            + "b3ee7000-b3ee8000 r--p 00050000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
            + "b3ed5000-b3ed6000 rw-p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so";
```

Second o/p

````
```
    String output2 = "\r\n"
    + "b3e74000-b3ec5000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
    + "b3ed8000-b3ee7000 ---p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
    + "b3ee7000-b3ee8000 r--p 00050000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
    + "b3ee8000-b3ee9000 rw-p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so";
````

```
   
   
   code part
   
   

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   
   String output1 = "b3e74000-b3ec5000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
       + "b3ec5000-b3ed4000 ---p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
       + "b3ee7000-b3ee8000 r--p 00050000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
       + "b3ed5000-b3ed6000 rw-p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so";

   Map<String, String> firstoutput = getMemoryAddressWithFileName(output1);

   System.out.println("firstoutput" + firstoutput);

   String output2 = "\r\n"
       + "b3e74000-b3ec5000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
       + "b3ed8000-b3ee7000 ---p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
       + "b3ee7000-b3ee8000 r--p 00050000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
       + "b3ee8000-b3ee9000 rw-p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so";

   Map<String, String> secoutput = getMemoryAddressWithFileName(output2);
   System.out.println("secoutput" + firstoutput);

   for (Map.Entry<String, String> foentry : firstoutput.entrySet()) {
       String foKey = foentry.getKey();
       for (Map.Entry<String, String> soEntry : secoutput.entrySet()) {
       String soKey = soEntry.getKey();
       String soValue = soEntry.getValue();
       if (soKey.equals(foKey) /* && !soValue.contains("[") */) {
           System.out.println( Memory address of virtual file process " + soValue
               + "is not changed. Memoery address if first execution is: " + foKey
               + " Memory address of second execution is: " + soKey);
        

       }
       }
   }
   }
public static Map<String, String> getMemoryAddressWithFileName(String response) throws IOException {

   Reader inputString = new StringReader(response);
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputString);
   Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   String[] processValues = null;
   String line = null;
       if (response != null) {
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       // System.out.println(line);
       processValues = line.split(" +", 6);
       // System.out.println(strings.length);
       if (6 == processValues.length) {

           map.put(processValues[0], processValues[5]);
       }
       }
   }
   // .out.println(map);
   return map;

   }
```

Comment: What are the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Pls take some time to format the code

Comment: What is not working? Your description talks about process name. But your code just checks for the presence of the same key between the two maps. In a way, the output from your code matches your intended output. But the approach sounds wrong. Maybe you should check the position or index or the whatever the second column is when comparing?

Comment: in hashmaps keys will be the address of file process eg: output1={ b3ec5000-b3ed4000=/lib/libm-2.31.so, b3ee7000-b3ee8000=/lib/libm-2.31.so} output2={{b3e74000-b3ec5000=/lib/libm-2.31.so, b3ec5000-b3ed4000=/lib/libm-2.31.so}, i want to compare the keys of same index positions of two maps are not equal. In real case in output2 expecting a change in the memory address of file process

Comment: @Thiyagu yes i want to compare the key's on two maps based on the index position only...in my current code, checking any of the first map key is present in second map keyset. not based on index position..but bit worried how it can be with hashmap

Comment: So the last column doesn't matter (`/lib/libm-2.31.so`) and only want to check if the value in the first column is same in two outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be best to use a `Map<String, List<String>` where the key is the filename with an index appended to it and the List holds the memory addresses for each file. And using `LinkedHashMap` (as you did) is required to preserve order of entry.

```
 String output1 = "b3e74000-b3ec5000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
         + "b3ec5000-b3ed4000 ---p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
         + "b3ee7000-b3ee8000 r--p 00050000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
         + "b3ed5000-b3ed6000 rw-p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so";

 String output2 = "\r\n"
         + "b3e74000-b3ec5000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
         + "b3ed8000-b3ee7000 ---p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
         + "b3ee7000-b3ee8000 r--p 00050000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so\r\n"
         + "b3ee8000-b3ee9000 rw-p 00051000 fb:00 1653       /lib/libm-2.31.so";
 Map<String, List<String>> map = getMemoryAddressWithFileName(new String[] {output1,
         output2});
 
 for (Entry<String,List<String>> e : map.entrySet()) {
     String mem1 = e.getValue().get(0);
     String mem2 = e.getValue().get(1);

     System.out.printf("File: %s - '%s' and '%s' are %s%n",
        e.getKey(), mem1,  mem2, mem1.equals(mem2) ? "equal" : "not equal"); 
 }
```

prints

```
File: /lib/libm-2.31.so#1 - 'b3e74000-b3ec5000' and 'b3e74000-b3ec5000' are equal
File: /lib/libm-2.31.so#2 - 'b3ec5000-b3ed4000' and 'b3ed8000-b3ee7000' are not equal
File: /lib/libm-2.31.so#3 - 'b3ee7000-b3ee8000' and 'b3ee7000-b3ee8000' are equal
File: /lib/libm-2.31.so#4 - 'b3ed5000-b3ed6000' and 'b3ee8000-b3ee9000' are not equal
```

This method returns a `Map<String, List<String>`

- it takes an array of two response strings as an argument.
- The Scanner is used to read from the string, taking advantage of the end of line delimiter.
- The `keyIndex` is used to alter the file names to act as unique keys.

The process is like this.

- for each line, split on the spaces followed by a leading slash
- the key is the file name appended with "#n" where `n` is the incremented keyIndex
- the value is memory address and is entered into a list. [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) makes this easy.  Check the JavaDoc link for details.
- then return and process the map.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> getMemoryAddressWithFileName(
        String[] responses) {
   
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String response : responses) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(response);
        int keyIndex = 1;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] subs = s.nextLine().split("\\s+(?=/)");
            if (subs.length > 1) {  // to take care of lone \r\n
                String key = subs[1] + "#" + keyIndex++;
                map.computeIfAbsent(key, v -> new ArrayList<>())
                        .add(subs[0].substring(0, subs[0].indexOf(" ")));
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```